# Вытащить данные из массива (php, мало кода)

Tags: php, массивы, циклы

Всем доброго времени суток. Работая со Steam API, получил массив данных. Вывел их на экран с помощью кода:

```
            $all_items = file_get_contents("ссылка");

            print_r($all_items);
```

Получил:

```
"items_game"
{
    "game_info"
    {
        "first_valid_class"     "1"
        "last_valid_class"      "1000"
        "first_valid_item_slot"     "0"
        "last_valid_item_slot"      "15"
        "num_item_presets"      "4"
    }
    "store_currency_pricepoints"
    {
        "10"
        {
            "GBP"       "8"
            "EUR"       "9"
            "RUB"       "700"
            "BRL"       "33"
            "JPY"       "1100"
            "NOK"       "90"
            "IDR"       "134900"
            "MYR"       "40"
            "PHP"       "500"
            "SGD"       "14"
            "THB"       "400"
            "VND"       "250000"
            "KRW"       "12000"
            "TRY"       "30"
            "UAH"       "120"
            "MXN"       "180"
            "CAD"       "13"
            "AUD"       "15"
            "NZD"       "15"
            "CNY"       "100"
            "TWD"       "300"
            "HKD"       "80"
            "INR"       "700"
            "AED"       "50"
            "SAR"       "40"
            "ZAR"       "140"
            "COP"       "30000"
            "PEN"       "40"
            "CLP"       "6700"
            "CHF"       "10"
        }
```

Вопрос заключается в том, можно ли вытащить данные и например вывести только данные, которые несёт в себе "first_valid_class" к примеру ? Пробую через foreach(), но выдаёт ошибку, что я ввожу не то, что нужно. Подскажите пожалуйста, как вытащить из этого массива только те данные, которые меня интересуют ?

Comment: А Вы не думали, ну, я не знаю, преобразовать строку в JSON? Хотя вроде не он. Покажите что возвращает `file_get_contents`. Строкой, а не картинкой, соц. сеть какая-то: "Вот фоточки моего кода!".

Comment: @Other Вот, отредактировал.

Comment: Честно говоря даже не знаю чем руководствовались те, кто создал такой ответ. Я бы дополнил это до валидного JSON и тогда уже `json_decode` в помощь.

Comment: @Other, это компания Steam, более 10 000 строчек. Так что, получить отсюда данные нельзя ?

Comment: Проверьте для начала в документации response format. Быстрое обращение к гуглу говорит, что steam api умеет отдавать json (дефолтно), xml и vdf (какой-то свой формат со своим парсером). Ваш кусок как раз похож на vdf

Comment: Получить данные можно, но после колдунств извлечения. Попробуйте узнать как вернуть JSON, не верю что стим в API не может его возвращать.

Comment: Своей редакцией Вы изменили суть вопроса (от "преобразования именно этого ответа в структуру" до "новая структура, все прошлые ответы, ранее, возможно, верные, идут лесом"). Так делать нельзя, задавайте новый вопрос, если нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Примерно так:

```
$all_items = file_get_contents("ссылка");
$json = json_decode($all_items);

echo $json->items_game->game_info->first_valid_class;
```

Насколько помню, Steam API возвращает валидный json, если дополнить ссылку параметром `&format=json`

Для разбора конкретно Вашего варианта, с форматом vdf можно воспользоваться библиотекой https://github.com/rossengeorgiev/vdf-parser - там 140 строк кода. Что в ответ дублировать не хочется.

Comment: Не является ответом. В вопросе возвращается явно не JSON.

Comment: В примере vdf: https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/KeyValues но ничто не мешает запросить именно json. Ответ, не по существу, согласен. Он для json варианта

Comment: Тогда надо описать что нужно сделать, чтобы получить JSON. В текущем виде Ваш код всегда будет декодировать в `null` и рухнет с ошибкой о невозможности выбрать свойства у `null`, что логично.

Comment: Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Опять же не решение заданного вопроса, но уже лучше.

Comment: @Other, Стим может возвращать vdf ( valve data format ). Но его можно конвертровать в JSON, при желании. Я вот переконвертировал и правил, можете подсказать пожалуйста, как например сейчас  получить только значения "color" или только "value" ?